# ItemStateChanged Error: java.lang.StackOverflowError JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estoy tratando de **imprimir la imagen** correspondiente de una **provincia** seleccionada en el `jCombobox` con el evento `ItemStateChanged`.

**¿Por qué me da error del tipo `StackOverflowError`?**

**Error:**

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at bbdd.Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(Conexiones.java:30)
    at bbdd.Conexiones.cargar_provincias(Conexiones.java:82)
    at interfaz.Combobox_Anidado.combo_provinciasItemStateChanged(Combobox_Anidado.java:228)
    at interfaz.Combobox_Anidado.access$200(Combobox_Anidado.java:20)
```

Quiero que cuando se seleccione una **Comunidad**, me imprima también la primera provincia ubicada en el `getSelectedIndex(0)`. Y una vez que se cambie el valor del `jCombobox_provincia` se actualice la provincia.

**Código:**

```
public class Combobox_Anidado extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public Combobox_Anidado() {
        initComponents();

        //Cargamos las comunidades en el jComboBox llamado "combo_comunidades".
        ArrayList<String> comunidades = new ArrayList<String>();
        comunidades = Conexiones.cargar_comunidades();
        //Creamos un iterator para recorrer el ArrayList.
        Iterator<String> i = comunidades.iterator();
        //Dato inicial del combo_comunidades.
        combo_comunidades.addItem("Seleccione una comunidad...");
        //Recorremos el iterator "i".
        while(i.hasNext()){
            //Añadimos a los items cada comunidad.
            combo_comunidades.addItem(i.next());
        }
    }

    private void combo_comunidadesItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                   
        //Guardamos en una variable string el valor seleccionado del combo_comunidades.
        String comunidad = (String) combo_comunidades.getSelectedItem();
        String capital = null;

        //Si el index del combo_comunidades es cero, NO existe comunidad: deshabilitamos.
        if(combo_comunidades.getSelectedIndex()==0) {
            combo_provincias.setEnabled(false);
            //Borramos todos los items del combobox.
            combo_provincias.removeAllItems();
            textfield_capital.setEnabled(false);
            textfield_capital.setText("");

            //Agregar una imagen a un JLabel.
            URL url_insertar = this.getClass().getResource("/imagenes/España.jpg");
            ImageIcon ico_insertar = new ImageIcon(url_insertar);
            lbl_fotoComunidad.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ico_insertar.getImage().getScaledInstance(lbl_fotoComunidad.getWidth(), lbl_fotoComunidad.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        }else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            //Habilitamos.
            combo_provincias.setEnabled(true);
            textfield_capital.setEnabled(true);
            lbl_fotoComunidad.setEnabled(true);

            //Creamos un ArrayList de String para las provincias.
            ArrayList<String> provincias = new ArrayList<String>();
            //Devolvemos las provincias dada una comunidad.
            provincias = Conexiones.cargar_provincias(comunidad);

            //Recorremos el ArrayList de provincias.
            Iterator<String> i = provincias.iterator();
            //Limpiamos los valores anteriores del combo_provincias.
            combo_provincias.removeAllItems();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                //Añadimos a los items con cada provincia.
                combo_provincias.addItem(i.next());
            }

            //Devolvemos las provincias dada una comunidad.
            capital = Conexiones.capital_de_comunidad(comunidad);
            textfield_capital.setText(capital);

            //Ponemos la foto de la comunidad seleccionada.
            ImageIcon foto = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/"+comunidad+".png"));
            ImageIcon foto_xyz = new ImageIcon(foto.getImage().getScaledInstance(lbl_fotoComunidad.getWidth(), lbl_fotoComunidad.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
            lbl_fotoComunidad.setIcon(foto_xyz);
        }
    }                                                  

    private void combo_provinciasItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                  
        String comunidad = (String) combo_comunidades.getSelectedItem();
        String provincia = (String) combo_provincias.getSelectedItem();

        if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            //Creamos un ArrayList de String para las provincias.
            ArrayList<String> provincias = new ArrayList<String>();
            //Devolvemos las provincias dada una comunidad.
            provincias = Conexiones.cargar_provincias(comunidad);

            //Recorremos el ArrayList de provincias.
            Iterator<String> i = provincias.iterator();
            //Limpiamos los valores anteriores del combo_provincias.
            combo_provincias.removeAllItems();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                //Añadimos a los items con cada provincia.
                combo_provincias.addItem(i.next());
            }

            //Ponemos la foto de la provincia seleccionada.
            ImageIcon foto = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/"+provincia+".png"));
            ImageIcon foto_xyz = new ImageIcon(foto.getImage().getScaledInstance(lbl_fotoProvincia.getWidth(), lbl_fotoProvincia.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
            lbl_fotoProvincia.setIcon(foto_xyz);
        }    
    }
}
```

Sin el método `combo_provinciasItemStateChanged`, funciona perfectamente al visualizar las comunidades, con las provincias me da ese error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código adiccional cargar_provincias():**

```
public static ArrayList cargar_provincias(String comunidad) {
        ArrayList<String> provincias = new ArrayList<String>();
        java.sql.Connection c = (java.sql.Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD("spain");
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            //Consulta para sacar todas las provincias de una comunidad.
            stm = c.createStatement();
            String consulta_provincias = "SELECT p.provincia FROM provincias AS p, comunidades AS c WHERE c.comunidad = '"+comunidad+"' AND c.id=p.comunidad_id";
            rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_provincias);
            //System.out.println("CONSULTA - PROVINCIAS DE X COMUNIDAD: Mostramos todas las provincias.");
            int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                String provincia = rs.getString("provincia");
                provincias.add(provincia);
                i++;
            }
            //System.out.println(provincias);
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Ha habido un error.");
        }     
        return provincias;
    }
```

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: @RuslanLópez Creo que la pregunta está perfectamente explicada y con código todo detalle, y al principio tengo escrito el error: "¿Por qué me da error del tipo StackOverflowError?"

Comment: Entonces por qué no veo el número de línea donde te dá el error?

Comment: @RuslanLópez No tengo error sintáxtico ni al compilar, el error lo tengo al elegir una comunidad y entonces me salga el error en el Output. Puse en el código del error en la explicación. Edité.

Comment: Agrega adicionalmente el driver de mysql que estás usando y un ejemplo de tu cadena de conexión, parece ser que es lo que está mal configurado.

Comment: @RuslanLópez Si estaría mal configurado diría que el error sería de la conexión, y si funciona el combobox_comunidades, entonces obviamente la conexión MySQL está bien.

Comment: Y eso dice: at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:422)

Comment: @RuslanLópez Sé que el error está en combo_provinciasItemStateChanged, porque si quito ese método el resto funciona perfectamente. Pero el error lo provoca el método combo_provinciasItemStateChanged.

Comment: Cuál es la línea 30 del fichero Conexiones.java?

Comment: @E.Betanzos c = DriverManager.getConnection(url + bbdd, login, password); Si quieres adjunto el método de conexión a la base de datos, pero funciona ese método porque sino no cargarían los combobox con las comunidades o provincias. El fallo está en el método "combo_provinciasItemStateChanged"

Comment: La traza dice esto:
at bbdd.Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(Conexiones.java:30)
    at bbdd.Conexiones.cargar_provincias(Conexiones.java:82)
    at interfaz.Combobox_Anidado.combo_provinciasItemStateChanged(Combobox_Anidado.java:228)

Por lo que el origen del problema está en el método `Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD` específicamente en la línea 30.

Comment: @E.Betanzos Ese método conexion_a_BBDD lo uso en todos mis programas y jamás me ha dado problemas. El problema está en el método combo_provinciasItemStateChanged porque si lo elimino, el programa funciona correctamente.

Comment: ¿Usas el mismo driver en ese programa en otras partes? Porque coincido con @E.Betanzos que una clase del driver corrupta sería el principal sospechoso. Normalmente este error viene dado por llamadas recursivas sin límite, pero el stack no indica eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como decía en mi comentario "Normalmente este error viene dado por llamadas recursivas sin límite,". Y tengo razón.

Por algún motivo (ahem, copy & paste sin pensar), en tu lista de provincia repites el comportamiento de la lista de comunidades. Si seleccionas una provincia, **borras la lista de provincias y la cargas de nuevo.**

```
provincias = Conexiones.cargar_provincias(comunidad);

//Recorremos el ArrayList de provincias.
Iterator<String> i = provincias.iterator();
//Limpiamos los valores anteriores del combo_provincias.
combo_provincias.removeAllItems();
while (i.hasNext()) {
  //Añadimos a los items con cada provincia.
  combo_provincias.addItem(i.next());
}
```

¿Y qué pasará al hacer esto? Pues que el item que has seleccionado cambiará, con lo cual pasará a ser otro, lo que hará que se invoque de nuevo *combo_provinciasItemStateChanged*. Que a su vez invocará de nuevo a *combo_provinciasItemStateChanged*, que a su vez...

Esto queda ocultado porque hay tantas llamadas por enmedio que en el stacktrace no es fácil ver la recursividad.

Solución: No toques la lista de provincias al seleccionar una provincia. Porque además de causar el error, es que no tiene sentido.